# Default route in MVC project with areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an ASP MVC 4 project which contains areas and is structured as follows:

- Areas

  - MyArea

    - Controllers

      - MyAreaController.cs
    - MyAreaRegistration.cs
- Controllers

  - HomeController.cs
- Global.asax

In Global.asax, I register first the area routes and then the global routes:

```
   AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
   RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

I have a default route in RegisterRoutes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
       "Default", // Route name
       "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
       new string[] { "Controllers" }
       );
```

Now, I want the default route of the project to point to an action (the login page with an return url as parameter) in MyArea without affecting the rest of the routes. I tried to set a default route in MyAreaRegistration:

```
 context.MapRoute(
       "MyArea_Default",
       "{controller}/{action}/{returnUrl}",
       new { controller = "MyArea", action = "LogOn", returnUrl = "/Home/Index" },
       new[] { "Areas.MyArea.Controllers" }
       );
```

This is working, the projects starts on the desired view. However, the problem is that many routes used across the project (for example /Home/Help) will match the MyArea_Default route since it is registered before the Default route. Trying to set the area DataToken in RegisterRoutes also messes up every other route not in the area.

How can I achieve a default route in the area without messing up everything else?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need `MyArea_Default` only for the single login action?

Comment: I want to hit it when accessing the exact route (https:// sitename/MyArea/LogOn?returnUrl=...) and when accessing the root route ( https:// sitename/ )

Comment: @RomanKoliada, changing the url for MyArea_Default as the root url ("") solves everything. It seems I wasn't very specific in my thinking about what I wanted to achieve (a root route and not a default route). Thanks.